# This F# code is not working

Tags: f#

This is not working...
I get  error FS0001: The type 'string' is not compatible with the type 'seq'
for the last line. Why?

```
let rec Parse (charlist) =
   match charlist with
   | head :: tail -> printf "%s " head
                     Parse tail
   | [] -> None

Parse (Seq.toList "this is a sentence.") |> ignore
```

Comment: Seq operates on a sequence and string isn't a sequence.

Comment: can someone please "Edit" the Title of that question..to make it easier. thx

Comment: @Lazarus - string is a sequence, but it's a sequence of chars where the inferred type of Parse requires a sequence of strings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `printf "%s " head` means that `head` must be a `string`, but you actually want it to be a `char`, so you'll see that `Parse` has inferred type `string list -> 'a option`.  Therefore, F# expects `Seq.toList` to be applied to a `string seq`, not a `string`.

The simple fix is to change the line doing the printing to `printf "%c " head`.